# How to make one button do a task that depends on which previous buttons has been clicked in Java android?

Tags: java, android, button

I am trying to make a simple math training app with levels , the plan is to make the user press on the button of the level he wants then the Go button will appear when he press Go the app starts and it generates random numbers based on the difficulty of the level he chose, now how to make the Go button play the app according to the level has been pressed , this is what i have tried so far but for some reason the app just crashes . p.s  this isn't the full code just the related issue of the code "

```
public void levelsWay(View view){

if (view.getTag().toString().equals("L1")) {
    a = rano.nextInt(21);
    b = rano.nextInt(51);
}

else if (view.getTag().toString().equals("L2")){
    a = rano.nextInt(101);
    b = rano.nextInt(151);
}
else if (view.getTag().toString().equals("L3")){
    a = rano.nextInt(151);
    b = rano.nextInt(501);
}
else if (view.getTag().toString().equals("L4")){
    a = rano.nextInt(501);
    b = rano.nextInt(1001);

}
```

}

public void generateQuestions() {

```
    levelsWay(null);

    c=rano.nextInt(4);
 switch (c) {
     case 0:op='+';
         break;
     case 1:op='-';
         break;
     case 2:op='*';
         break;
     case 3:op='/';
         break;
         default:op='?';
 }
    sumtextview.setText(Integer.toString(a) + op + Integer.toString(b));
```

}

```
public void start(View view) {
    starts.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Gamelayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    playAgain(findViewById(R.id.pp));


}
```

Comment: You might want to use RadioButtons for selecting the level rather than regular Buttons.

Comment: Hmmm but is there a way to make it work with the buttons? why isn't the tag working?

Comment: Where do you set the tag?

Comment: Please share the layout .xml file of your activity

Comment: @Code-Apprentice   i set the tag in my xml file sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the tag inside your xml layout file where the buttons are stated and then inside your code you getTag from the view and use it accordingly something as follows

Set tag for each button as follows

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_level_1"
    android:tag="L1" // Setting tag here />
```

Then inside the onClick listener do the following

```
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.firstButton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String level = view.getTag().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "Level Selected : " + level);
        // Apply the rest of the logic
    }
});
```

Comment: i did set the tag in my xml sir , but i didn't know i had to make a click listener  i thought i didn't have to , and the tag will do the job . but i will do as you said , but then even if it worked how will i call the onclick method in the generateQuestion method which will be called in the start method?

Comment: I am sorry i am not able to understand what you are trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: for example i have made a click listener for every button , okay , now i want to make all these click listeners happen in one method using the if condition how to call the clicklisteners and put them in one method